# changing font size of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIButton` which displays a text, with the following code:

```
 [button setTitle:@"Join this group" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

however, how do I change the font size for this?
I tried

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-MT" size:8.0];
```

but I think it's a totally different thing.
Or at least how do I make the text to adjust to the size of the button frame.
Should I just use textLabel.text instead?

Comment: `button.titleLabel.font` is the right way, however as far as I know you cannot set a min font size for the button's label like in a UILabel.

Comment: well I did that and it didn't adjust the font

Comment: `titleLabel` *is* a `UILabel`, so you definitely can set `minimumFontSize` on it. Don't know how well it will work, but a button's label *is* a UILabel.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The reason that the code you're posting isn't working is probably because Arial isn't present in iOS. You can change the properties of a `UIButton`'s `titleLabel` just like any other instance of `UILabel`. Read about that [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW40).

So, you can change the font size with something like:

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
```

You can choose a font by name, but not all fonts are available on iOS. [Here's](http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts) a list of ones that are.

Comment: Swift 3: 
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)